# AUCTeX prompting for optional arguments

Tags: beamer, auctex, optional-arguments

My general question: is there a way to get AUCTeX to prompt me automatically for an optional argument of a command when I invoke it with `TeX-insert-macro` (i.e. <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>)?  (like it does when you invoke, for instance, `\newcommand`)

My specific question: is there a way to get AUCTeX to prompt me automatically for an optional overlay specification when I invoke the `\alert` command with `TeX-insert-macro` (i.e. <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>alert</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opposite of this problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/disable-auto-overlay-prompt-in-auctex

Answer (score 2):

I asked the AUCTeX mailing list, and Mosè Giordano kindly provided the following answer:

You have to manually patch the file style/beamer.el in your AUCTeX
installation.  Replace the line

```
'("alert" 1)
```

with

```
'("alert" TeX-arg-beamer-overlay-spec 1)
```

Remember to byte-recompile the file with M-x byte-recompile-file RET RET.

Comment: I wonder if there is a more robust way to do this, one that would not require me to recompile /style/beamer.el everytime I update AUCTeX

Answer (score 1):

Try to add one of the following commands (depending on your needs) to your *.emacs* file:

1. `(setq TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'show-optional-args)`
2. `(setq TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'show-all-optional-args)`

the difference between the two is as described in Auctex documentation:

> User Option: TeX-insert-macro-default-style
>        Specifies whether 'TeX-insert-macro' will ask for all optional
>        arguments.
>        If set to the symbol 'show-optional-args', 'TeX-insert-macro' asks
>        for optional arguments of TeX marcos, unless the previous optional
>        argument has been rejected.  If set to 'show-all-optional-args',
>        'TeX-insert-macro' asks for all optional arguments.
>        'mandatory-args-only', 'TeX-insert-macro' asks only for mandatory
>        arguments.

Although this suggestion may not be applicable to *beamer* macros as noted by @ArashEsbati however it may answer the first part of the question that is:

> Is there a way to get AUCTeX to prompt me automatically for an optional argument of a command when I invoke it with TeX-insert-macro (i.e. C-c RET)? (like it does when you invoke, for instance, \newcommand)

Comment: Thanks Hafid.  Unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: With your code, Emacs will throw an error at startup since it looks for a variable `show-optional-args` which is not defined.  As described in the manual, you need symbols.  Hence, you need `(setq TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'show-optional-args)` (note the `'`).  Even quoted, I'm afraid that your suggestion will not work since the function`TeX-arg-beamer-overlay-spec` is defined in a way that it doesn't respect the settings in your answer.

Comment: Thank's to @ArashEsbati for his relevant remarks especially about quoting the  symbols `show-optional-args` and `show-all-optional-args`. So I reedit my answer accordingly.